# Wercker setup environment step error: Guest command failed with exit code -1: mkdir -p “/pipeline”

Tags: wercker

I used ubuntu. I see the same question here, but the answer link is wrong.
I have the error message :

```
"Guest command failed with exit code -1: mkdir -p “/pipeline”"
```

I do not know why. The /pipeline already exits but the *-p* option should answer that all is ok. Any idea ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: show what question here? you haven't linked anything. you'll also need to show what commands you're running for anyone to help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the configuration of an environment, specifically on Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if the image has its USER parameter set to a non-root user.  You can check the user with the command `docker inspect ubuntu` (or whatever image you are using).  What happens is wercker starts up a new container from that image, and because the image has user=bob for example, it is trying to do the `mkdir` as `bob`, but `bob` does not have permission to write to that path.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I deleted the final CDM step in the build of my docker container so the CMD is by default /bin/sh and then the build wercker was successfull.